# On dropdown select, redirect to (Rails 3)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, carmen

I would like to have a collection of all countries displayed as a dropdown. When a country is selected, I'd like to redirect to the root_path with the selected country as a parameter [i.e. root_path(:country => selected_country)].

I've found the Carmen gem for the list of countries, but can't seem to get it to function properly as specified above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a change event handler to the select box that posts the form. In your controller action that handles the post, perform the redirect.

http://api.jquery.com/change/

http://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 1):

I probably wouldn't bother with a form post; I'd just set the `window.location` and construct the URL with the `root_path` helper and a manually-appended country.

I *would*, however, validate the country parameter if present.

IMO this approach is a bit inelegant, and I tend to like Derek's suggestion better, but it's an option.

Comment: Yeah, I considered this but his question included reference to a rails route and this solution would result in replicating that route info on the client. Not the worst thing. I'd probably do it your way just to avoid writing the controller method.